# Proof verification: these two notions of AoC are equivalent.

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I want to prove these two definitions of AoC are equivalent in ZF. As Set Theory is kinda confusing me at the moment, I'd like someone to verify my proofs.

> **Definition 1.** For any relation $R$ there is a function $F \subseteq R$ with $\textrm{dom} \ F = \textrm{dom} \ R$.

> **Definition 2.** For any set $I$ and any function $F$ with domain $I$, if $(\forall i \in I)(F(i) \ne \varnothing)$, $\prod\limits_{i \in I} F(i) \ne \varnothing$ (where $\prod$ is the generalized Cartesian product).

Assume Definition 2. Let $R$ be a relation and, for any $r \in \textrm{dom} \ R$, let $R_r := \{(x, y) \in R : x = r\}$. Let $F := \{(r, R_r); \ r \in \textrm{dom} \ R\}$. I think it's easy to show all of these are sets. Also, $F$ is a function by definition and clearly $F(r) \ne \varnothing; \ \forall r \in \textrm{dom} \ R$. Then the function guaranteed to exist by Definition 2 satisfies Definition 1.

Assume Definition 1. Let $F$ be some function defined on $I$. Define a relation $R$ so that, for every $i$ in $I$, $R$ contains all of the elements of $\{i\} \times F(i)$ (and nothing else). This is a set because it's a definable subset of $I \times \bigcup \bigcup F$. Then the function guaranteed to exist by Definition 1 satisfies Definition 2.

Although, why is $R$ a definable subset of $I \times \bigcup \bigcup F$? I've noticed that I don't actually know how to show that, given a relation $R$, the range of $R$ is a definable subset of $\bigcup \bigcup R$. I'm using Enderton's book and he doesn't prove this, merely states the set exists because it's a subset of $\bigcup \bigcup R$. Do we allow parameters in our formulas here? As in, can I reference any set as if it were a constant of the underlying language? Because I don't think it's possible to do this without them.

Comment: Yes, the separation schema (and the replacement schema for that matter) allows parameters.

Comment: Your definition of $F$ in showing that Definition 2 implies Definition 1 cannot be correct. Note that your sets $R_r$ are indexed by elements $r\in\mathrm{dom}(R)$, but your description of $F$ has $(r,R_r)$ with $r\in R$. I think you meant $F=\{(r,R_r)\mid r\in\mathrm{dom}(R)\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks, I've fixed it. Is the idea okay in general?

Comment: Your work is confusing because you are using the same letters to mean different things in different places, but the general ideal is right. To go from Version 2 to Version 1, you consider the family of relational classes, and the "choice" function gives you a function contained in the relation. To go from Version 1 to Version 2, you consider the relation from $I$ to the image given by $iRx\iff x\in F(i)$, and the function contained in $R$ gives a choice function.